# When selecting * FOR UPDATE in mysql using innodb does it lock all the results that match the query?

Tags: mysql, innodb

For example:

```
SELECT * FROM table1 ORDER BY id DESC FOR UPDATE
```

will this lock all the rows?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it locks all the rows. From the [documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/innodb-locking-reads.html):

> A SELECT ... FOR UPDATE reads the latest available data, setting exclusive locks on each row it reads. Thus, it sets the same locks a searched SQL UPDATE would set on the rows.

Comment: thanks. will accept this as the answer as soon as it lets me!